# Is it possible to make a multisig wallet where one of the owners can cancel a transaction?

Tags: solidity, blockchain, wallets, multisignature

The objective is to create a wallet, that depends on a time-frame (e.g.. 2days) before a transaction gets executed. Before this time frame is reached, one of the owners could cancel the transaction if they thought it was from a compromised owner.

Comment: To get a helpful answer you might have to narrow down your question a bit, and add little more context about what it means for "thinking it was from a compromised owner".

Answer (score 4):

yes, it is possible.

you will need an additional function same as execute function, which would cancel the tx.
The process is gonna be the same as the execution.
This is just going to be an additional feature.

Comment: Thank you so much! But yes, that's it! I want to have a variable that keeps track of the timeframe, and have a cancel() function, so one of the owners can cancel this if needed.